# Efficiently finding average values of indexed rows and columns in a symmetric tensor

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a (200 x 200) tensor which is symmetric (obtained by multiplying another 200 x 300 matrix with its transpose). Each row (and the corresponding column) belong to a specific category. Each category and its indexes are kept in a dictionary. Here is what it looks like:

```
print(data.shape) # tensor containing data
print(cat_idx).   # category index dictionary
```

`
torch.Size([200, 200])

{'Album': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
'Animal': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
'Artist': ...
...
`
The above data says that the values in rows (and columns) 0 through 10 contains the distance data for category Album. There are 15 categories.

Now I want to convert this into a 15x15 tensor where there is the average distance for each category. That is row 1, col 1 contains the average distance between all points for Album, row 1 col 2 would contain the average distance of all points belonging to Album category and Animal category and so on.

I used couple of loops and a lot of code to get this (See below)
mean_score_by_cat_row = torch.empty((0, cosine_scores.shape[1]))

```
for i, cat in enumerate(categories):
  cat_scores = data[cat_idx[cat]]
  cat_row_mean = torch.mean(cat_scores, 0, True)
  mean_score_by_cat_row = torch.cat((mean_score_by_cat_row, cat_row_mean), 0)

mean_score_by_cat = torch.empty((len(cat_idx), 0))
for i, cat in enumerate(categories):
  cat_scores = mean_score_by_cat_row[:, cat_idx[cat]]
  cat_col_mean = torch.mean(cat_scores, 1, True)
  mean_score_by_cat = torch.cat((mean_score_by_cat, cat_col_mean), 1)
```

This does not seem like the right way to do this with tensors. Is there a better way to do this? Am I even doing the right thing.

Comment: Seems like the solution will have to involve a loop if each category has a different number of corresponding rows

Comment: Thank you. Keep exploring options and post back if I find one.